# Combine categorical data in separate columns to a single column with a category indicator

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that gives me result in this form.

```
+---+-------+--------+-------+
| id| First | Second | Third |
+---+-------+--------+-------+
| 1 |   id1 |   null |  null |
| 2 |  null |   null |   id2 |
| 3 |   id3 |   null |  null |
| 4 |  null |    id4 |  null |
| 5 |  null |    id5 |  null |
+---+-------+--------+-------+
```

Here First, Second, Third are categorical columns where for each row only one of the columns will have an entry while others would be null.

I want to convert this data in PostgreSQL to the below form where all the categorical data is combined into a single column and category:

```
+---+----------+----------+
| id| data     | category |
+---+----------+----------+
| 1 | id1      | First    |
| 2 | id2      | Third    |
| 3 | id3      | First    |
| 4 | id4      | Second   |
| 5 | id5      | Second   |
+---+----------+----------+
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your second table is identical to your first. Can you update your post with the proper desired output table?

Comment: You could try using a CASE statement: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Comment: please check your second table, table1 and table2 both are similar

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
select id,
  case 
    when "First"  is not null then 'First'     
    when "Second" is not null then 'Second' 
    when "Third"  is not null then 'Third' 
  end as category_indicator,
  coalesce("First", "Second", "Third") as category_data
from ( - your - query - here - ) as t;
```

| id | category_indicator | category_data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First | id1 |
| 2 | Third | id2 |
| 3 | First | id3 |
| 4 | Second | id4 |
| 5 | Second | id5 |

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/806ee/4).
Unrelated but using mixed case and reserved words for identifiers is not a good idea. Both require double quotes.